# How to add Poi Scala library to Play project?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

I want use Poi Scala library in the my Play framework project, And I added Poi Scala library to libraryDependencies in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "info.folone" %% "poi-scala" % "0.11",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0-RC1",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-testkit" % "2.0.0-RC1" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.5.0.8",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.28" % "test",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4" % "test",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0", 
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1"
)
```

by instruction [Poi Scala](https://github.com/folone/poi.scala)

but, when I do command "play update" appear following error:

```
[warn]  module not found: info.folone#poi-scala_2.10;0.11
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   c:\tools\play-2.2.1\repository\local\info.folone\poi-scala_2.10\0.11\iv
ys\ivy.xml

[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/boyfox/.m2/repository/info/folone/poi-scala_2.10/0.11/po
i-scala_2.10-0.11.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/folone/poi-scala_2.10/0.11/poi-scala
_2.10-0.11.pom

[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/info/folone/poi-scala_2.10/0
.11/poi-scala_2.10-0.11.pom
```

Anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It seems like the last version of poi-scala that was published was `0.9`, see bintray (https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/info.folone:poi-scala_2.10?from=general), sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~folone), and maven central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/folone/poi-scala_2.10/). Maybe this is an oversight, or maybe they moved to a different maven repo. I'd recommend opening an issue at https://github.com/folone/poi.scala.

Comment: thanks @gourlaysama for your recommendation, but first need to determine why not found exists files. I found this file in Sonatype snapshots repository: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/webapp/browserepo.html?4  and http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/info/folone/poi-scala_2.10/0.11-SNAPSHOT/  . And I tried add Sonatype repo resolver to my build.sbt file, but didn't help.

Comment: these are snapshots, not releases. You can add `resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")` and change your dependency to `"info.folone" %% "poi-scala" % "0.11-SNAPSHOT"` to get it. But this is not a release, just some arbitrary intermediate build.

Comment: oh thanks @gourlaysama! I found my mistake I added Sonatype snapshots repo here is such: resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" and get parse error. Thanks!

Comment: @mr.boyfox It appears you found a solution. Would you mind posting it as an answer and accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gourlaysama said:

> It seems like the last version of poi-scala that was published was
>   0.9, see bintray (bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/…), sonatype (oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~folone), and maven
>   central (repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/folone/poi-scala_2.10). Maybe
>   this is an oversight, or maybe they moved to a different maven repo.
>   I'd recommend opening an issue at github.com/folone/poi.scala.

This is right, library is indeed not in maven repository. And I opened an issue at github.com/folone/poi.scala by recomendation of @gourlaysama :

[Issue](https://github.com/folone/poi.scala/issues/30#issuecomment-35213244)